# Meteor Twitter login "Internal Server Error"

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I've deployed my app to Meteor's servers with Twitter login. So the first time I loaded it up, it asked me to configure the Consumer Key and Secret and something went wrong during saving those details. Now every time I go to log in with Twitter, it pops up the new window but returns immediately with a Meteor dialog box saying "Internal Server Error".

What are my options?

How can I reset my app's OAuth state if I can't access the database (as it's on Meteor's servers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reach into your collection and access the mongo shell using

```
meteor mongo yourapp.meteor.com
```

Look for a collection called `meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration` and delete it

And for your user specific OAuth state get into the `users` collection. Your OAuth should be in `services.twitter` & `services.resume`

Answer (score 9):

An alternative way to fix this issue is to set/reset the access key/secret programatically when the application loads.

```
// ensure this runs server side

Meteor.startup(function() {
  Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
    service: "twitter"
  });
  Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
    service: "twitter",
    consumerKey: "XXX",
    secret: "XXX"
  });
});
```

The same method can be applied for configuring other networks. The key values could also be loaded in dynamically using environment variables or with Meteor.settings: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_settings